# PHP session and TCP connection?

Tags: php, http, browser, tcp

Is a PHP session (https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) guaranteed to use the same TCP connection? Some context: our web service is load-balanced, so if the user, in the same PHP session, establishes a new TCP connection, it might connect to a different server which does not have the PHP state/session info saved earlier.

Comment: I don't think so.  Look into using sticky sessions for the load balancer.

Comment: Definitely no. Sticky sessions at the LB or a shared backing store for the session data.

Comment: Our LB (or the team that runs them) only allows 5 minutes max of persistence/stickiness. But the user can keep a browser window, and its session, open for longer. So perhaps a shared data store is the way to go...

Comment: And @Sammitch the answer is No because it's a cookie-based mechanism, right? The user can keep the browser open after the TCP connection drops.

Comment: @flow2k no. The cookie only contains the session ID, so the client either needs to always hit the same server that contains its session data, or the session data needs to be available to all servers.

Comment: @Sammitch right - thanks. The data is stored server-side, and the issue manifests itself when the user keeps the browser open for an extended period, during which the initial TCP connection drops, and a new one has to be established.